# Read XML from URL as a string

Tags: java, xml, string

I have a file as https://localhost/myeg.xml
I want to read the file as string in Java.
Can somebody help me if there is a separate library or any way else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

```
URL url = new URL(myfile);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int read = -1;
StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
while ((read = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length) != -1) {
  bld.append(new String(buf, 0, read, "utf-8"));
}

String s = bld.toString();
```

- This assumes `utf-8`, if the originating host does specify encoding, I would use `.openConnection()` and figure out the "content type" (and encoding) before reading the stream.
- For performance you may want to wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`.
- You probably want a `try-finally` to close the `InputStream`

Comment: that's an `InputStream`. he said he wants `String`. Finish the example ;)

Answer (score 4):

[common-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
URL url = new URL("https://etc..");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
String str = IOUtils.toString(input, "utf-8"); //encoding is important
input.close(); // this is simplified - resource handling includes try//finally
```

Or see examples in [the official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). See [this example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/TrivialApp.java?view=markup)!

Comment: Wait 'till you discover you need authentication and header manipulation to get the file! ;)

Comment: one by one. you can't throw everything at somebody that doesn't know much about the subject